# AWK insert variable value in system()

Tags: linux, awk

I need to get the value of the `names` variable in the `system` function, but I didn't find any information how to do this. This line doesn't work at all `system("ps -p "+names[n-1]+" -o comm=")`. 
As result program have to splits the process path and get the process name by its pid.

```
awk '{
n=split($0,names,"/"); 
printf "%s\n",system("ps -p "+names[n-1]+" -o comm=")
}' <<< "/usr/lib/firefox/firefox/1319/1000"
```

Comment: `names[n-1]  == $(NF-1)`

Comment: What are you hoping will be output by the `printf`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `+` signs:

```
printf "%s\n", system("ps -p " names[n-1] " -o comm=")
```

Comment: That would print the success/failure status of the `system()` call, not the output of the call to `ps`. You should also quote the names[n-1] within the shell.